# Python program keeps taking input

Tags: python

```
def main():

    n = int(input().strip())

    a = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    b = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
    a.sort()
    b.sort()
    total=0
    i=0
    j=0
    while i!=len(a):
        while j!=len(b):
            # print('a[i]', a[i],'b[j]',b[j])  
            if a[i]<b[j]:
            # print('in a[i]<b[j]')
                i+=1
                break
            if a[i]==b[j]:
                total+=1
                i+=1
                j+=1
            # print('total is ',total)
                break
            else:
            # print('in else')
                j+=1
    if total==n:
        print(n)
    else:
        print(total+1)

main()
```

Input:

```
4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 3
```

The program keeps asking for input even after i press the "enter" button on my keyboard. while for other types of input it works perfectly fine

Comment: did you press enter key after entering arrays `a` and `b`?

Comment: yes, i did @AlbinPaul

Comment: Put your input in question also. And then you can also read it from file like `python program.py < input.txt`

Comment: Are you trying to find the count of greater elements in a and b?

Comment: What do you think it should do instead? Why? What does "works perfectly" mean? what problem is the code intended to solve?

Comment: @NielGodfreyPonciano, No i'm not trying to do that, I'm just trying to solve a hackerrank problem of 'beautiful pairs'

Comment: It is not asking for more input. It is stuck in an infinite loop. You should think carefully about your algorithm, and perhaps use a debugger to study the behaviour of the code.

Comment: It seems to be going into an infinite loop, not requesting additional input. Probably add a few `print` statements to see what's going on when you run it.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, the program is meant to check if there are similar elements in both the array. I was trying to solve the 'beautiful pair' problem from hackerrank community

Comment: When the input is as you show, what should the correct answer be? Can you solve the problem with pencil and paper? Can you explain, step by step, how to get that answer? Telling us the name of a problem on some other website is not helpful.

Comment: Think carefully about whether you really want nested loops for this. You are aware that this is *not the same* as using both conditions to control a single loop, right?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I got the reason why I'm stuck in the while loop, but I don't quite get the part that "this is not the same as using both conditions to control a single loop", can you please elaborate?

Comment: Also, why am I getting in stuck in the while loop even before assigning my values inside the list? @KarlKnechtel

Comment: When you write `while i!=len(a):` and then `while j!=len(b):`, it comes across to me like you are trying to do a single loop that will run as long as it is true that `i!=len(a)` *and* it is *also* true that `j!=len(b)`. Am I correct? If so - can you think of a way to write that properly in Python? Possibly a way that actually uses the word `and`?

Comment: "why am I getting in stuck in the while loop even before assigning my values inside the list" I can guarantee you that this is not happening. Try `print` ing the values of `a` and `b` immediately before the loop.

Comment: I tried printing the values of `a` and `b` before the loop and it was printing the right stuff, so my problem was with the loop, also i used the `and` statement to group `i!=len(a)` and `j!=0` together and I wasn't stuck in the loop. But why am I getting stuck when using nested loops? @KarlKnechtel

Comment: ...For the reason explained in the answer that you already read and acknowledged? I don't understand why you're asking me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236638/discussion-between-red-devil-and-karl-knechtel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is not taking any more inputs, it just runs in an infinite loop in your `while` statement because of the last digits of `a` and `b` namely 4 and 3.

For the first 3 digits `1 2 3`, the value of i and j are both 3.

Then while comparing the last digits `4` and `3`, it isn't True for this

```
if a[i]<b[j]:
```

Nor this

```
if a[i]==b[j]:
```

Thus it executed else which only increments j making i=3 and j=4.

Now you're stuck because it will never go inside the inner while loop (since j is already 4) which means it will never increment i again thus will never reach the length of 4.

```
    while i!=len(a):
        while j!=len(b):
```

Want proof? switch your inputs for a and b

```
1
1 2 3 3
1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I understand where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
    def getInput(n): #another method.
    a = list()
    for x in range(n):
        a.append(input().rstrip().split())
    return a

def main():

    n = int(input().strip())
    a = getInput(n)
    b = getInput(n)
    a.sort()
    b.sort()
    total=0
    i=0
    j=0
    while i!=len(a):
        while j!=len(b):
            # print('a[i]', a[i],'b[j]',b[j])  
            if a[i]<b[j]:
            # print('in a[i]<b[j]')
                i+=1
                break
            if a[i]==b[j]:
                total+=1
                i+=1
                j+=1
            # print('total is ',total)
                break
            else:
            # print('in else')
                j+=1
    if total==n:
        print(n)
    else:
        print(total+1)

main()
```

The first problem is that your question is quite imprecise. You've said it stops taking input but have also expressed the idea that it runs infinitely. These cannot both be true given what we have here.

The problem with getting input was that you called map() with int and list().rstrip().split(), as 1st and 2nd arguments when the Python library states that the function requires the method you want to call as 1st arg and the 2nd must be an iterable, or a collection as per:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

So if you wanted to use map() you also needed to have a list full of items because map() uses the provided function on each value in the given list. in other words: you needed data to run map() on prior to calling it.

I am assuming that you're implementing an algorithm and the print()'s executed properly when I ran it with them uncommented. My solution above should at least allow you to get back to developing your algorithm.

I simply deferred the call to a method defined called getInput() which takes the number of values to take (n) and returns the list of them retrieved from the input.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I got a clearer understanding of the part where I was going wrong